# Why hiding part of the HTML when using media-query does not work

Tags: html, css, media-queries, display

Trying to practice I have created a landing page mock up and trying to hide an element in css media query.

```
@media (max-width:800){

 .right-pane{
    display: none;
    }
}
```

But it does not work when resizing the screen.
Would appreciate your feedback

https://codepen.io/yanivlt/pen/eYNdKRV

Comment: 800 what? px? em? elephants?.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace 'max-width: 800' to 'max-width: 800px'. Can you try this.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.right-pane{
    display: none;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `px` to the `max-width` parameter.

Using your example, this should work:

```
@media (max-width:800px){
  .right-pane {
    display: none;
  }
}
```